# jquery prevent form from submiting if ajax error exists

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit

I couldn't find an answer to what I'm looking for here. I'm using ajax to check if a username exists in a database, if the user exists an error is displayed in the form. But I'm trying to prevent the form from being submitted if that error exists. I've tried event.preventDefault() but I'm not sure if I'm using it right, or if I'm using it wrong.

My JS code is:

```
$(".check").blur(function () {
    var username = $(".check").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "validateUser.php",
        type: "post",
        data: "username=" + username
    }).done(function (result) {
        if (result == "true") {
            // CODE TO RUN IF ERROR DOESN'T EXIST
        } else {
            // CODE TO RUN IF ERROR DOES EXIST
            // CREATE THE ERROR MESSAGE AND DISPLAYS IT
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: submitting a form on blur ?

Comment: @MohammadAdil - Yes - to check if a username already exists even before submitting the form

Comment: use `return false` instead of `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: is karthikr == Vince ?

Comment: @MohammadAdil that's a nice one :P

Comment: really?? `return false` :P

Comment: @vince you are not submitting a form in your code.

Comment: @Jai the form is submitted when the user clicks the button. When the error exists it goes to the form submit page and gives me a mysql error "duplicate entry"

Comment: Okay you mean if you get `true` then you want form to be submitted or am i missing something here.

Comment: @Jai right. but if the form it returns "false" then I want to prevent submission to the form.

Comment: @Vince i just added a answer have a look at it if this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Do the validation on form submit as well as the blur.

```
function checkUsername(username) {
    var username = $(".check").val();
    return $.ajax({
        url: "validateUser.php",
        type: "post",
        data: "username=" + username
    }).then(function (result) {
        var def = $.Deferred();
        if (result == "true") {
            // CODE TO RUN IF ERROR DOESN'T EXIST

            def.resolve();
        } else {
            // CODE TO RUN IF ERROR DOES EXIST
            // CREATE THE ERROR MESSAGE AND DISPLAYS IT

            def.reject();
        }
        return def.promise();
    });
}

$(".check").blur(checkUsername);
$("#myform").submit(function(e){
    var self = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    checkUsername().done(function(){
        // username was ok
        self.submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to prevent your form's submission you have to call `preventDefault()` on `event` instance of a handler for [submit](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) JavaScript event of a form.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
    return !$(this).hasClass("error");
});

$(".check").blur(function () {
   var username = $(".check").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "validateUser.php",
        type: "post",
        data: "username=" + username
    }).done(function (result) {
        if (result == "true") {
            $("form").removeClass('error')
        } else {
            $("form).addClass("error");
        }
    });
});
```

So your ajax has will add a class error or remove it if its valid. If the form is submitted it is canceled if it has the class error.

Ajax is async and therefore you can't return it directly. Because the code will continue to run and not wait for the `done` function.

Answer (score 0):

use `return false`  instead of `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: The event has already happened by then, return false won't work any better.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(".check").blur(function (event) {

    // Prevent Default the event here...
    event.preventDefault(); 

    var username = $(".check").val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "validateUser.php",
        type: "post",
        data: "username=" + username
    }).done(function (result) {
        if (result == "true") {
            // CODE TO RUN IF ERROR DOESN'T EXIST
            $("form").submit();  
        } else {
            // CODE TO RUN IF ERROR DOES EXIST
            // CREATE THE ERROR MESSAGE AND DISPLAYS IT                             
            $(this).focus();
            alert('An error occurred!');
        }
    });
});
```

### Some points here:

1. You didn't even added the `event` in the function and you were calling `event.preventDefault()`.
2. In case, the result is `"true"`, you can simply submit the form or run your code.
3. Else , just put the `focus` back to the text-box and display an alert message.

Comment: The event has already happened by the time you try to prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments i think you should try this one:

```
if (result == "true") {
    $(this).closest('form').submit();
} else {
    $(this).closest('form').submit(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Comment: Works great, I had to update it a little to check if the error field is shown. If it does, then I call the preventDefault, and if it doesn't, then i leave it alone.